# Specifying Excel workbook from custom ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, ribbon

I have an .xlam with a custom ribbon defined. It works great, the ribbon shows up when I open the workbook, and my macros run when I click buttons.

I want to have multiple versions of the add-in open at once (Title & File name reflect version number, so there's no problem opening both). I can open both simultaneously, and see both old & new tabs on the ribbon.

What I can't figure out is how to explicitly chose which workbook to use. This means that both "Update" buttons call the same subroutine.

```
Version1.xlam update button -> Version1 Update subroutine
Version2.xlam update button -> Version1 Update subroutine
```

I tried setting `onAction` to `ThisWorkbook.basUpdater.Update` or `ThisWorkbook.Update` but neither worked.

**Does anyone know how to specify the target workbook from the UI XML?** (or know whether & why it's not possible to do that).

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui"> 
  <ribbon> 
    <tabs> 
      <tab id="mytab" label="My Tab"> 
        <group id="abt" label="About"> 
          <button id="Update" size="large"
            label="Update" onAction="basUpdater.Update" /> 
        </group > 
      </tab> 
    </tabs> 
  </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you must use a unique ID for `<tab id=`, `<group id=`, `<button id=`, etc. (Unique not per add-in but globally for all add-ins). So eg try `<tab id="Version1mytab"` etc. and then `ThisWorkbook` should work in `onAction`